# Rewrite URL with id in Yii

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess, yii

I have an project made with Yii and I use a page with variable **id**.

My detail with **id** variable before update urlManager on config/main.php that was stopped.

I configured correctly the config/main.php like these lines:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules'=>array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '/'
            ),
        ),
```

In .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

After done that parameters I have the follwing SEO-friendly url:

```
http://www.verinmuebles.co/permalink-id.html
```

Where id is a ID to get content related but I get an error 404 with this URL. What I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
'permalink-<id:\d+>.html'=>'page/view',
```